# ruby: Trouble understanding classes and defining variables with @

Tags: ruby, class, rspec

I am currently doing an rspec tutorial and am having difficulties with reading the tests. The current test I am trying to read is:

```
 describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
```

I can understand what it is asking me to do: create a class Book and a method inside that class to capitalize. However my thoughts on how to code this is completely wrong (I have seen an example of code that works in this case)

What I tried to do:

```
class Book
    def initialize(book)
        @book = book
    end

    def title(@book)
        @book.capitalize
    end
end
```

Solution that ended up working:

```
class Book

    attr_reader :title

    def initialize(title=nil)
      @title = title && title.capitalize!
    end

    def title=(new_title)
        @title = new_title && new_title.capitalize!
    end
end
```

I do not understand exactly what the @ does. I thought it was to create a variable that works throughout the entire class. In addition, I am wondering why @title is used instead of @book (which is specified in the rspec test).

In addition, I am struggling with the "before do" part of the code and why it asks for @book = Book.new

Also the part with the && is confusing as well. Why is it not ok to just put @title = title.capitalize!

I would be happy to clarify any of this if it does not make sense (I know this post is long).

Comment: I would use the non-exclamation-mark version of `capitalize` here. The exclamation-marked version will modify the passed argument, which might lead to weird bugs: `title = "hello"; book = Book.new(title); title #=> "Hello"`

Comment: Also, a suggestion: don't worry about rspec until you've got your head around classes, messages, and instance variables.

Comment: @hdgarrood I am currently learning ruby through an rspec tutorial. I had assigned readings and the coding they want me to do are the Test First tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ is a fundamental construct in Ruby: an instance variable for a class. So you don't have to pass it as a param within methods of the class. It's known by the entire instance of the class. See, for example, [Instance Variables and Accessors](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables) for details.

So the following isn't really valid since you don't pass instance variables as method parameters:

```
def title(@book)
    @book.capitalize
end
```

The `&&` will only go to the second statement if the first is true or not `nil`. For example

```
def initialize(title=nil)
  @title = title && title.capitalize!
end
```

Will set the class' instance variable `@title` to the parameter `title.capitalize!` as long as `title` isn't `nil`. If `title` is `nil`, then `@title` will be set to `title` (i.e., `nil`). So if the class is created without a parameter, then `@title` will be set to `nil` and an error won't be generated from calling `nil` with the method `capitalize!`.

Comment: Am i correct in thinking `@title = title && title.capitalize!` says: if there is a title then capitalize, if not, `title = nil` 

Would it fail if the first title were not there and a title were not passed?

Also why `@title` instead of `@book` (does it even matter?)

Comment: @SaiDandamudi, yes, it will set `@title` to `title` if `title` is `nil`. And it would fail if the first `title` were not there and `title` were `nil` since you'd be attempting to call `.capitalize!` on a `nil` object. `@book` or `@title` doesn't matter as long as the class usage is consistent.

Comment: I see; I am assuming @title is cleaner just based on what it is doing. What is the point of the rspec test calling `@book = Book.new` then? This is truly what confused me. I thought it was asking me to create an instance variable by the name of `@book` that, when called, would create a new object for the `class Book`

Comment: @SaiDandamudi I can't see all of the test, but it looks like it's ensuring that, when it starts, it has a valid, fresh `Book` object in `@book` rather than having it default to `nil`.

Comment: In that case, does that mean I should disregard anything with 
`before do 
<method does this>
end`
The rest of the tests are just indicating what types of words should be capitalized or not (e.g. first words in the title should, but not "the" "and" or prepositions etc.)

Comment: @SaiDandamudi it all depends upon what's inside that block. I couldn't say you should always disregard.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. I understand some of my initial problems but now I have a lot more to research and understand.